# Using CodeDeploy set permissions using AppSpec or script

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, deployment, permissions

I am new to CI/CD and just configured my first on-premise deployment app. I encountered that after deployment the files have changed permissions.

BTW, Is it a normal behavior?

Now I am figuring out how to set the permissions back. I have identified 2 alternative ways:

1. Appspec
2. Shell script triggered by appropriate lifecycle event

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Just use `chmod` to set permissions you want.

Comment: I want it to be executed automatically vie either way described above.